# Is Is this an abelian group?

Tags: group-theory, discrete-mathematics, abelian-groups

> Given $p,q$ are  prime numbers $\{pm + qn:m,n \in \Bbb Z\}$.
>   Is this an abelian group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The set $\{pm+qn:m,n\in \Bbb Z\}=p\Bbb Z+q\Bbb Z$ which is a subgroup of $\Bbb Z$ and hence an abelian group

Comment: And, if $p\not=q$, then $p$ and $q$ are relatively prime, so $p\mathbb{Z}+q\mathbb{Z}=\mathbb{Z}$.  (If I understand the OP's question correctly, $p$ and $q$ are prime).

Comment: Yes that's true @MichaelBurr

Comment: So if I follow this reasoning, than I don't need to show the requirements of an abelian group (closure, an identity element, inverse elements, commutativity and associativity)?

Comment: No; just make sure that $p\Bbb Z+q\Bbb Z$ forms a subgroup of $\Bbb Z$,otherwise its enough

Comment: Any more doubts ??Can consider accepting it then @Thomas